# Kafka Scala: How to get offset value from OffsetAndMetadata class

Tags: scala

I'm looping thrice on `offsets`:

1. Get `TopicPartition` & `offset`
2. Get `TopicPartition` & `OffsetAndMetadata`
3. Get the delta between the producer & consumer

I'm wondering if I can get the `offset` value from `OffsetAndMetadata` but I'm not sure how. I couldn't find examples online to get this value. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    event.progress.sources
      // Ignoring sqs / jms sources their offsets
      .filter(source => source.description.toLowerCase().contains("kafka"))
      // ex offset :
      //    "endOffset" : {
      //      "rcs-enriched-event" : {
      //        "8" : 31376,
      //        "11" : 39114,
      //        "2" : 39376,
      //      } ...
      .foreach(source => {

        /// Map[Topic,Map[Partition, CurrentOffset]]
        val jsonOffsets = objectMapper.readValue(source.endOffset, classOf[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]])
        jsonOffsets.keys.filter(key => topics.contains(key))
          .foreach(topic => {
            val offsets: Map[String, Int] = jsonOffsets(topic)
            val consumedPartitions = new ListBuffer[TopicPartition]()
            val topicOffsetList = new ListBuffer[Int]()

            val mapTopicPartitionOffset = offsets
              .keys
              .map(partition => {
                val tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition.toInt)
                val offset = offsets(partition).toLong
                (tp -> offset)
              })
              .toMap

            val mapTopicPartition = offsets
              .keys
              .map(partition => {
                val tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition.toInt)
                val oam = new OffsetAndMetadata(offsets(partition).toLong)
                (tp -> oam)
              })
              .toMap


            for(topicPartition <- mapTopicPartitionOffset){
              consumedPartitions += topicPartition
            }

            try {
              val kafkaPartitionOffset = kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava)

              for((topicPartition,offset) <- mapTopicPartitionOffset){

                val bbCurrentOffset =  offset

                // latest offset
                val partitionLatestOffset = kafkaPartitionOffset.get(topicPartition)

                // Partition offset delta
                val delta = partitionLatestOffset - bbCurrentOffset

                topicOffsetList += delta.abs
              }
            } catch {
              case e: Exception => {
                log.error(s"${consumerGroupId} Could not get Kafka offset", e)
              }
            }

            try {
              kafkaConsumer.commitSync(mapTopicPartition.asJava)
            } catch {
              case e: Exception => log.error(s"${consumerGroupId} Could not commit offset", e)
            }

            //log.info have the group id (unique id), the topic, cumulative consumer lag delta
            log.info("consumerGroupId: " + consumerGroupId + " topic: " + topic + " lagDeltaSum: " + topicOffsetList.sum)
          })

      })
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean `OffsetAndMetadata.offset is where the incorrect code is`? does it throw exceptions? What do you mean by "incorrect"?

Comment: @AminMal `offset` is actually incorrect, the error: `cannot resolve symbol offset`. As referenced by @OneCricketeer https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetAndMetadata.html I'm just not familiar enough with scala on how to extract the `offset` value from the class

Comment: Actually it's not about not knowing Scala, you need to know the library, so please read library docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get an offset value without both a topic and a partition. You're already iterating for each topic, and your JSON shows that you have keys in an map of partitions, so this question is simply "how do you get values from a map?"

More importantly, do you actually *need* to get the offset from `OffsetAndMetadata` when you have the same value two other places?

More specifically, you don't need both `mapTopicPartitionOffset` and `mapTopicPartition`. Each contain the exact same information, one just has an object as a value with null metadata property.

You also have `offsets` map, whose values are all the offsets for the current topic you're iterating, and the keys are its (consumed) partitions.

Each contain the offset values that you want

You only need `mapTopicPartition` to use with `commitSync`, so try this

```
.foreach(topic => {
    val offsets: Map[String, Int] = jsonOffsets(topic)
    // for getting end offsets
    val consumedPartitions = new ListBuffer[TopicPartition]()
    // convert to values accepted by Kafka Consumer API
    val toCommit = offsets
          .keys
          .map(partition => {
            val tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition.toInt)
            consumedPartitions += tp
            val oam = new OffsetAndMetadata(offsets.get(partition).toLong)
            (tp -> oam)
         })
        .toMap

    // could also use toCommit.keys instead of separate list 
    val kafkaPartitionOffset = kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava)
 
    for((topicPartition,oam) <- toCommit) {

        val bbCurrentOffset = oam.offset() 
        // or offsets.get(String.valueOf(topicPartition.partition))
```

Comment: Both alternative methods in the code comment doesn't seem to be working, but the primary examples are working great!

Comment: `toCommit.keys` returns a Scala Set, which would need converted to a Java list